# VSCode: enable .Net Core Debugger in portable IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

In these days I'm trying these projects:
- Visual Studio Code: I chosethe portable (.zip) executed from USB memory.
- .Net Core (.zip package again), which I decomprissed into the same USB memory as the previous one.

When I try to generate a new C# into VSCode project, first I had the problem around how to invoke the .Net core folder (aka dotnet decomprissed folder). Until now, just I had to put in the console the absolute path location of the dotnet executable -again, from the folder I decomprissed from the zip file-.

But then I try to debug the console application after these commands:

```
dotnet new
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

I see the following error:

```
The .NET Core Debugger is still being downloaded. See the C# Output Window    
for more information.
[ERROR]: C# Extension failed to install the debugger package
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using VSCode as compiler/debugger? then why not use visual studio?

Comment: Because we want a lightweight environment not so sophisticated in order to test and execute test units. Just like Sublime Text. Also we saw sessions in which its possible to debug and compile in VSCode  C# scripts. The problem we found is when we try the same steps in portable packages.

Comment: Then why not **SharpDevelop**?

Comment: Remember, portable solutions with portable toolkits.

Comment: what do you mean portable, do you mean SharpDevelop is not portable?

Comment: Man, I think Sharpdevelop is outdated and does not fully integrate with the tons of plugins that another wellknown code editors like Atom or ST.

Comment: The debugger package VSCode C# extension tried to download is large. You will have to have a reliable internet connection to let that download. This is related to your machine configuration and network settings, not a real question at all.

Comment: Lex Li... how can I download it?

Comment: @MigRome close VSCode and open it again. Then open the .NET Core project folder in it and that should trigger another download attempt.

Comment: But how can I see if the download is completed?

Comment: @MigRome Visual Studio Code should show the progress of downloading at bottom-right hand corner, as shown in the image:  https://sgdotnet.blob.core.windows.net/random/downloading-packages-process-in-vscode.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw this error on my PC too, turns out as of now the C# debugger doesn't support 32-bit Windows system, there is an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/844.

Check if you are using a 32-bit Windows, if yes, upgrade to x64.

Comment: Thanks James.. so this confirms the issue. Unfortunatelly there is no way to upgrade to x64. I have to discard VSCode. ;(